# Reading and updating specific child of xml

Tags: xml, windows-phone-7

I have xml file in isolated storage. Snapshot is attached. I have two questions
[image]

1. I Only want to only read first "imageTime" tag (highlighted in yellow.
2. I want to update "imageTime" tag of any node, say that of third "Fact" node (circled in red).

Kindly gave me code for these two questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `XDocument` to parse the XML file:

```cs
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("PATH/TO/YOUR/INPUT");
    var v = doc.Descendants("imageTime").ToArray();
```

Then to,

1- read the first *imageTime* element:

```cs
    string value = v[0].Value;
```

2- modify third *imageTime* element:

```cs
    v[2].Value = "yourNewValue";
```